# How to decipher the hr return value "-1072875847" returned by a COM function?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, return-value, ms-media-foundation

I am using VC++. the hr return value returned by a COM function is "**-1072875847**".
Can anyone kindly let me know how to decipher the hr values to their actual meaning. 
specifically What does "-1072875847" stand for ?

Thank in advance.

Comment: looks kind of like an integer-overflow even though the number does not fit any bit-number I know.
what were you doing, expecting?

Comment: The Visual Studio debugger does a reasonable job of interpreting HRESULT codes for you. Something to consider in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The codes are [`HRESULT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb446131.aspx) values and are better read in hex. This one is `0xC00D36B9`, which is Media Foundation Error "An object ran out of media types to suggest therefore the requested chain of streaming objects cannot be completed." ([`MF_E_NO_MORE_TYPES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd206746%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Comment: Thank you for the quick help. But can you plz let me know how did you map the hex error code "0xC00D36B9' to be a Media foundation error?  How did u figure out this is MF_E_NO_MORE_TYPES ? It would be very helpful if u also let me know the procedure?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick,

```
std::cout << "Error: " << std::hex << hrStatus << std::endl;
```

And you need to go to the header file 
mferror.h  and search for it. 
Or google it. Good luck